# Execute awk from python-no error-no output

Tags: python, linux, awk

this code works fine from terminal/bash script:

```
 awk '/^(name|count|region)/{sep = (/^region/? ORS:OFS);gsub(/^[^:]+:[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$/, "");printf "%s%s", $0, sep}' output.txt>1.txt
```

Trying to execute it from inside python:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
    import sys
    import json
    import re
    import os
    import subprocess




  def bash_command(cmd):
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')


bash_command = ('''"awk '/^(name|count|region)/{sep = (/^region/? ORS:OFS);gsub(/^[^:]+:[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$/, "");printf "%s%s", $0, sep}' output.txt> 1.txt"''')
```

No errors but 1.txt is not created

Comment: Why on earth are you calling a scripting language from another scripting language? why not implement what `awk` is doing in python?

Comment: because can't get desired output from python itself

Comment: You should ask the question again, stating what data you have, and what you are trying to do with it, and what problems you are having, in python - rather than hacking things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a function with a string parameter, you have to use this pseudo-code. Instead, you were setting your function name as a string tuple.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import json
import re
import os
import subprocess

def bash_command(cmd):
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')


bash_command("echo test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you are looking for, but you can use the [`python-awk`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-awk) library

> pawk is a python-based replacement for awk.
>
> It uses python for line-by-line processing of files

Although the package looks like it could a cleanup.

https://github.com/jasontrigg0/pawk